# How to refer to an Excel worksheet by index rather than name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Woe is me, I have an Excel workbook with a gazillion sheets; each with its own unique, non-sequential name. I want to refer to these sheets using their indices rather than names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4227-excel-reference-sheet-by-number.html). It comprises two phases:

#### Phase 1: Write a function which obtains the sheet name by index

1. Bring up the VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) Window  (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).
2. Insert a new code Module (e.g. on the menu: Insert > Module).
3. A subwindow for the new module will come up. In the text area, insert the following code:

   ```
   Function SHEETNAME(number As Long) As String
    SHEETNAME = Sheets(number).Name
   End Function
   ```
4. Exit the VBA window.

#### Phase 2: Use the `SHEETNAME()` function

You might expect to now be able to write formulae such as:

```
=SHEETNAME(12).B3
```

Unfortunately, that does not work, since SHEETNAME() returns a string, not a worksheet. You will need to use Excel's indirect lookup function, like so:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&SHEETNAME(12) &"'!B3")
```

This will be a reference to the cell in column 3 of row B of the 12th sheet in the workbook.

*Note:* Sheet numbers are 1-based.