# Excel relative reference to other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have a workbook, where each sheet represents a city.  There is a bunch of data in each, city's sheet, and some summary fields at the top.  Let's say for each city's sheet, cell A1 is the city name, A2 is the population, and A3 is the number of houses.  So, for example, let's say the first sheet is for Anytown.  Its first 3 cells (A1-A3) might be:

```
Anytown   25,000    8,000
```

(Note: Besides being in cell A1, the city name is also the name of the sheet)

I'll have many more sheets like this for other cities.

Now, I want to create a "summary" sheet that automatically pulls those same 3 fields from all of the other cities' sheets into columns.  For example, its A, B, and C columns would look like this:

```
Anytown   25,000    8,000
Busytown  35,000    9,000
Tinytown  5,000     1,000
etc...
```

So far, I can create the cell references for the first row, referencing the fixed cells in the first sheet like:

```
Anytown!$A$1   Anytown!$A$2    Anytown!$A$3
```

That gives me the first row, but I have many sheets to reference, and I don't want to have to type in the sheet name for every row.  I want that row to be automatically repeated, pulling in the A1-A3 cell references from all of the other cities' sheets.

I tried dragging the lower right corner of the first row's cells and dragging down, but that just creates a bunch of references to Anytown's sheet.  So, it appears that my references to the sheet name are absolute.  Is there a way to make them relative so that this will work?

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: What you're really interested in is [**How to get a list of the sheet names of the current workbook?**](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+sheet+names+list) Answer - [**For example, like this...**](https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/) Once you have this list, the [**INDIRECT() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) will do the rest of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one of the new string/array functions Excel recently came out with, `TOCOL`, this is now easy:

```
=TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet4!A1,,)
```

The parameter in the function is a range where the range is in the sheets part of the reference and the cell on each sheet is always A1.

Often a spreadsheet will be organized with a contiguous set of sheets that one would like to do something like you desire with. In those cases, the reference is easy to create:  Just enter the formula and click on the first sheet in the set of sheets, and on the cell, A1 in this case, then navigate to the last sheet in the set of sheets and click on the same cell. Or just type it out, of course.

So long as the sheets stay contiguous, that's all you need. If you insert or delete sheets INSIDE the two "bookend" sheets, that action will update the list of all the included sheets' A1 cells.

Naturally, B1 and C1 can be done in the same manner.

Its output is workable for the `SORT` function, so an alphabetical, say, list need not require the sheets to be in alphabetical order.

I have not experimented, but it ought to take any buildable set of cells. That would probably let one use non-contiguous sheets, though obviously it would be harder to set up. If one can use such a range, then one would surely also then be able to use any cell from a page, not just the same cell on each page.

The more inclusive formula:

```
    =TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet4!A1:C1,,)
```

leads to a single column list as in Sheet2's three cells, then Sheet3's, and so on. That would be amenable to extraction and repositioning using, probably, something like `INDEX` and cleverness.

(Sister function `TOROW` works similarly, producing a 1-D array like just described above.)

The real gem is likely `MAKEARRY` which requires an appropriate `LAMBDA` to reposition things. I have not worked with that one yet, but it's surely your best bet for a single formula in a single cell populating your whole listing.

Comment: That worked great!  One minor issue that I found was that if the field is a date field that is copied over, but the value is blank, it comes out as "1/0/1900" if formatted as a date on the destination sheet.  I solved that by setting the following custom date format: mm/dd/yyyy;"1/0/1900";;@

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I got an inspiration from this answer: [How to refer to an Excel worksheet by index rather than name?](https://superuser.com/questions/1679074/how-to-refer-to-an-excel-worksheet-by-index-rather-than-name)

You can use a combination of a custom function which returns the name of worksheet based on it's index and the "INDIRECT" function like so:

Open VBA editor, insert new module and copy following function into it:

```
Function sheetNameFromIndex(ByVal sheetIndex As Integer) As String
    sheetNameFromIndex = Worksheets(sheetIndex).Name
End Function
```

Then create your summary worksheet and put this function in A1:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & sheetNameFromIndex(ROW()) & "'" & "!1:1048576"),1,COLUMN())
```

Expanding this function horizontally will pull values from the first worksheet, expanding it vertically will pull the same values from subsequent worksheets (each wokrsheet will have it's own row)

Comment: Thanks!  This is looking good so far.  One issue, though... If the sheet name has spaces in it, then it does not work.  The value of the cell shows as "#REF!" if the sheet it references has spaces in the name.  How can I fix that?

Comment: @JoeMjr2 Hey good point, I didn't realize this would be an issue. I updated the formula to work for worksheets with spaces in names.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make Comments, but an important item came up when the poster used the earlier solution.

The following can do the trick and solve the return of "0" when a blank is in one of the referenced cells:

```
=INDEX(IF(TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet4!A1:C1)="","",TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet4!A1:C1)),SEQUENCE(3,3),)
```

It would seem the `IF` belongs inside the `TOCOL`, but it won't work that way. Works nicely though this way. Basically it checks the `TOCOL` returns for blanks and has a blank passed in its return if it does, otherwise the normal return is passed on. So before a "0" is passed out to `INDEX`.

(The "1/0/xxx" is how Excel displays a zero.)

Also, it turns out `INDEX` not only solves the extra problem of turning `TOCOL`'s single column back into three columns, but is useful in another way. It is able to directly use `TOCOL`'s output as a dynamic range where several other functions needed another formula in the middle for them to refer to;  they couldn't use the output directly as a full range.

And `INDEX`'s output can be sorted by `SORT` if of interest.